# Unit test - Karma - Jasmine - BsModalService code coverage is not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write the unit testing for 1 of the method, it was expecting the parameter of **template: TemplateRef** and inside method. I am showing and hiding the modal by using
**this.modalService.show(template, CommonConst.CONFIGFORSMALLMODAL)**. There is no error but code coverage is not covered.

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="add_btn_point" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="add(validateTemplate)">
 Add </button>
<ng-template #validateTemplate>
    <div class="alert-box">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">
          Add
        </h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="messageText text-center">
          <p>
            {{errorMessaage}}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" >
          Save
        </button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Component:

```
addFileQueryDataPool(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
if(true) {
        this.valModalRef = this.modalService.show(template, CommonConst.CONFIGFORSMALLMODAL);
      } else {
this.valModalRef.hide();
}
  }
```

Unit Test:

```
it('should call the addFileQueryDataPoint() method when clicking on the links', () => {
    const obj = spyOn(component, 'addFileQueryDataPoint');
    
    //let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#add_btn_point'))
    //el.triggerEventHandler('click', null)

    let buttonDebugElems: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('#add_btn_point'));
    buttonDebugElems[0].triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    const button: HTMLButtonElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#add_btn_point');
    button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    fixture.detectChanges()
    
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(component.addFileQueryDataPoint).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Is it any way to skip this method. I was tried adding x in front of it() method. Method skipped but coverage is not increasing.

Please advice, how to write unit test case for above code. Advance thanks

Comment: `if(true)` what is the purpose of this?

Comment: For testing purpose I have hard-coded the value. It's always true. Inside block I am opening the model